# Load xml-file and display only vertices

Tags: mxgraph

How can I load the following draw.io file in my mxGraphModel and display only the vertices and NOT the edges?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mxfile host="www.draw.io" modified="2019-09-25T08:10:42.119Z" agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" etag="rVOYKV4DccHE-o70O52h" version="11.3.1" pages="1">
  <diagram id="VCf34-Iv6E_k61pAP0pe" name="Page-1">
    <mxGraphModel dx="1248" dy="594" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="1100" math="0" shadow="0">
      <root>
        <mxCell id="0"/>
        <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
        <mxCell id="VXw29pc5vOmcNuhHpu7d-5" value="" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="VXw29pc5vOmcNuhHpu7d-2" target="VXw29pc5vOmcNuhHpu7d-4">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="VXw29pc5vOmcNuhHpu7d-7" value="" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="VXw29pc5vOmcNuhHpu7d-2" target="VXw29pc5vOmcNuhHpu7d-6">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>

        [... some more vertices and edges ...]

      </root>
    </mxGraphModel>
  </diagram>
</mxfile>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to load it? If yes, where is that part of code?

Comment: @NickAth thanks for your reply.
Yes, I loaded the file and got an xml-Document Object (doc):
var req = mxUtils.load(filename.xml);
var doc = req.getXml(req); // xml-Dokument

But I have no idea, how to continue

Comment: Check the code below :)

Comment: Your example code stops with a TypeError: cell is null

Comment: Please take a look in the updated answer

Comment: That runs in an endless loop.
Maybe something is wrong with my xml document. Please have a look at https://pastebin.com/KtW13vVB

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my code. No endless loop anymore, but an empty cells-array.

Comment: That's weird, could you post your actual xml? I do not see any vertices in the xml you loaded

Comment: The xml file that I posted at pastebin (look previous posts) is the actual file. I am right, that vertices have a parameter vertex='1'? If so, there  are 5 vertices in the file (e.g. the last mxCell)

Comment: Yes, vertices have vertex attribute = 1, I tested the code snippet with your xml and it works,
https://pasteboard.co/IASGBJ8.png

Comment: Looks correct! Could you please mail the code snippet for loading the xml-file? I guess, there is my mistake

Comment: There is no point in mail you the code snippet for loading the xml-file, this way nobody else other than you will benefit from the question, you can post in your question the whole process (how your upload your file and how you parse it), then maybe I could find what is wrong

Comment: Sorry,  my fault. I try to load my xml-file this way:
`var filename = 'test1.xml';

        var req = mxUtils.load(filename);
        var doc = req.getXml(req); // xml-Dokument
`

Comment: You should firstly store your xml into a string file and then execute the code in the updated answer

Comment: Is there a way to use the xml-file straightaway?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "straightaway"?

Comment: Use it directly without transform it into a string

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since you have the `doc` object that contains the xml loaded you can parse and draw only the vertices using the code below:

```
let xml = '<root>...</root>'; //your xml
let doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
let codec = new mxCodec(doc);
codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
let elt = doc.documentElement.firstChild;
let cells = [];
while (elt != null)
{ 
    let cell = codec.decode(elt);
    if(cell != undefined){
        if(cell.vertex){
          cells.push(cell);
        }
    }

    elt = elt.nextSibling;
}

//add the vertices in the graph
graph.addCells(cells);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you process a string. I don't have string, but an xml-file. How do I load the xml-file and prepare it to process it with your the given function?

If it has to be a string: How do I load the xml-file and convert it into a string?